# QTranslator not working when used in a if statement

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtranslator

I added a translation file using Qt Linguist. Then I proceeded to use `QTranslator` when my app is loaded:

```
    QTranslator translator;
    bool loaded = translator.load(":/notizie_en_UK.qm");
    bool installed = app.installTranslator(&translator);
    qDebug() << "Adding translation" << loaded << installed;
```

This works fine.
Now I wanted to use the translation only if the system language wasn't already the default language so I did the following:

```
QLocale::Language phoneLang = QLocale::system().language();
qDebug() << "LANGUAGE" << phoneLang << (phoneLang != QLocale::Italian);
if(phoneLang != QLocale::Italian){
    QTranslator translator;
    bool loaded = translator.load(":/notizie_en_UK.qm");
    bool installed = app.installTranslator(&translator);
    qDebug() << "Adding translation" << loaded << installed;
}
else{
    qDebug() << "Using italian";
}
```

However this doesn't work. If a system in English for example, the translator doesn't work and the default language of the app is used (in this case Italian).

The output from `qDebug()` is:

> LANGUAGE QLocale::English true
>
> Adding translation true true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `translator` object is destroyed as soon as the program execution exits your `if` statement's body where it was defined. What you can do is:

```
[..]
if (phoneLang != QLocale::Italian) {
    QTranslator *translator = new QTranslator;
    bool loaded = translator->load(":/notizie_en_UK.qm");
    bool installed = app.installTranslator(translator);
    qDebug() << "Adding translation" << loaded << installed;
}
[..]
```

However you must take care off destroying `translator` object yourself when necessary.

**UPDATE:**

You may define a parent of your translator that will clean up its child objects. For example:

```
// The application is translator's parent.
QTranslator *translator = new QTranslator(app);
```